# Round floats decimals to nearest tenth in PHP

Tags: php

After converting currencies, I get a float that would look something like `2.68`.

Tried rounding up with `ceil($input / 10) * 10` but that doesn't work for floats.

**So is there a simpler way for rounding floats to the nearest tenth?**
I'd like to get `2.70`.

---

The more complicated way for me to do this would be to `explode` the float at the `.` then round `68` with `ceil`. And then combine them.

But what If the number is `2.96`. It will need to be `3.00` rounded, so this makes it really complicated.

Comment: What about using `round($input,1)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply got the math wrong, it should be multipled-then-divided, not the other way around:

```
ceil($input * 10) / 10
```

But that only rounds up. Rounding in each direction works with `round`...

```
round($input * 10) / 10
```

But wait, `round` has a second param, just for this! :)

```
round($input, 1) // round with precision of 1 digits after the decimal point
```